# Create Cloudfront Distributions through AWS-SDK from NODEJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Manually I have created static site in AWS s3 then I created clouldfront url with SSL and Its working fine

Now I am trying to create same process from NODEJS application

I could create Static site AWS S3 through AWS SDK from node application **but I couldn't create  clouldfront url through AWS SDK**

I have researched lot and got urls but its making confusing me how to implement

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/cloudfront/command/CreateDistributionCommand/

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-cloudfront

Can I get any example code with minimal steps ?

Comment: I might suggest you to use AWS SAM (https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/) to do the same thing.  It's a really nice framework for deploying code to AWS.  You could adapt your nodejs application to instead have AWS SAM in your local environment and shellexec to it to do the deployment given a certain set of parameters.